# Timed Relay Circuit Wiring and Calculating

Tags: capacitor, relay

I am trying to learn electronics and I have a simple circuit in which a button is pressed, a capacitor is charged, then triggers a relay. (With my limited knowledge) I am using a 4.7μf cap and a 470K ohm resistor to charge the capacitor. If I am not mistaken, the delay should be about 2.2 seconds. However, I don't see any delay.

Here is my Fritzing diagram:

[image: Fritzing Diagram]

Relay Info:

```
Coil Voltage = 5vdc
Input Voltage = 6vdc
```

Comment: Is your relay turning on? what voltage? Using a 470K ohm resistor, I suspect your relay isn't turning on at all. We need a little bit more information. What is coil voltage of relay?

Comment: The relay turns on. I updated the post with addition info. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How much time are you giving the capacitor to charge? Those components make for a very long [time constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) (2.2 seconds). The capacitor may simply not be sufficiently.I think you are miss-understanding certain concepts here.

Comment: @sherrellbc - I could be misunderstanding the basics. Thats why I posted the question. Perhaps you can point out what I might be doing wrong? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using 220 ohm resistor (Red, Red, Brown). This timing is about 1000us. (R*C = 968 us). . If you desire a delay of 2.2 seconds you will need additional components.

Comment: The frizzing diagram does not have a symbol for 470ohm, so in my real circuit its 470ohms not 220ohm. Sorry for the confusion. Can you please elaborate on additional components?

Comment: If you have 470K ohms in series with the relay, at 6 volts, then only 12 uA will be available to energize the relay. View it as a voltage divider. You cannot be having a 470K ohm resistor in series with your relay coil, at 6 volts, and having the relay turning on. Your time delay (RC) will need to be followed by an amplifier (comparator) that can source the required current of the relay.

Comment: @PhilVallone . You have also indicated that you are using 4700 ohm, not 470K ohms. Even using 4700 ohms, you will only get 1.27mA (6/4700) for relay coil current.  Additionally,    4700*4.7uf=.022 seconds (22ms)

Comment: @maria - that was a typo.

Comment: @PhilVallone . . From a beginner point of view, the simplest solution to the timing is to use 470 ohm and 4700 uf capacitor to achieve the 2.2 second timing (not recommended). I would suggest asking another question regarding, "How can I achieve 2.2 second delay in turning on a relay".